How to find the norm of the functional in $C^\infty[0,1]$
From $C^\infty[0,1]$ to $C^\infty[0,1]$ I have the functional $f[x(t)]=2x(t)+e^{x(t)}$. I believe, that the norm of such functional is $2+e$, because it is a sup of $f[x]$ and $\lVert x\rVert\leq 1$ and it approaches $1$. But how do I prove it? Or am I wrong?

A functional on a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ is a map $\ell:V\to K$ (usually you impose linearity as well, but some times you want to deal with non-linear functionals). What you have is just a map from the vector space into itself. Furthermore, the norm of an operator is usually something reserved for linear operators, and your $f$ is not linear. So what is it you want to compute? Are you asking about $$\sup_{\substack{x\in C^\infty[0,1] \ \lVert x\lVert\leq 1}}\lVert f(x)\rVert,$$where $\lVert,\cdot,\rVert$ is the supremum norm on $C^\infty[0,1]$?

Let $x\in C^\infty[0,1]$ have norm one (that is $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)|=1$), then $$\|f(x)\|=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|2x(t)+e^{x(t)}|=\sup_{y\in\mathrm{Image}(x)}|2y+e^y|\leq\sup_{y\in[-1,1]}|2y+e^y|=2+e$$
And this bound is reached for instance by the unit norm function $x(t)=2t-1$, or $x(t)=1$.
